# (Angular) Make checkox disable or enable <mat-slide-toggle>

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

I have a list of Users to select for a team. Imagine that i select a User, he can either be active or inactive in his team. Now, if i don't select him at all, i should not be able to either activate or deactivate him. 
This is made by a checkbox and a slider, like this:

[image]

When I click the checkbox, i need to disable the toggle. I have tried doing this by:

```
$("#2048").prop('disabled', true);
```

or

```
document.querySelector('[name="' + '#2048' + '"]').disabled = true;
```

Does not work either (And yes, i know that IDs should not be numbers, but it's because every toggle is inside a *ngFor. Still, i can use them as numbers, as jQuery can select them anyway)

Either way, i strongly believe that the only way to do something like this is to data-bind the 'disabled' attribute as some back-end variable that returns either a 'true' or 'false' value.

Something like:

```
<mat-slide-toggle 
[id]='data.id' 
class="status" 
[disabled]='disableVariable'
>Active
</mat-slide-toggle>
```

and then:

```
disableVariable = someFunction(); //that returns true or false
```

This works, but the variable is 'too generic', i mean, every single slider will become disabled. Another problem is that this is not 'real-time', so i cant disable and enable multiple times.
Basically, it does not do the job.

What should i be doing here? If i had a way to select those tags using their unique ID's, that would fix the problem, but neither jQuery or Javascript's Query selector can disable or enable this tag.

EDIT:

A litle more of my code:

```
    <div id="table" *ngFor="let data of User; let i = index">

        <div [id]='data.id' *ngIf='data.user== 0' class="item">

            <label class="container" style="width: 90%">

                <input
                type="checkbox" 
                *ngIf='data.status== 0' 
                id={{i}} 
                class="checkbox" 
                color=primary
                checked>

                <span class="checkmark"></span>

                <div *ngIf='data.status== 0'>{{data.name}}

                    <mat-slide-toggle 
                    [id]='data.id' 
                    (change)=toggle(data.id) 
                    *ngIf='data.status== 0'
                    color=primary 
                    class="status" 
                    >Active
                    </mat-slide-toggle>

                </div>
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
```

When i add the ([ngModel)], my checkboxes stop working, and yes, i'm importing the FormsModule

Comment: You should not use jQuery with angular please check how to implement form in angular: https://angular.io/guide/forms

Comment: in the example you has how disabled the toogle: https://material.angular.io/components/slide-toggle/examples

Comment: It does not work as my checkbox is not material ( and it cannot be )

Comment: Does [this demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-66dfz3) helps you?

Comment: Whoa, it's really what i need. Can you post it as an answer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use two-way binding to update the status of the checkbox as follows:

Add [`[(ngModel)]`](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel) and disabled property to the input field

```
// Declare variable in component
CheckboxVar:boolean;

// In Html write below code
<input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="CheckboxVar" [disabled]="!CheckboxVar">

// Disabled checkbox when checkboxvar = false;
<input type="checkbox" [disabled]="!CheckboxVar">
```

Update `CheckboxVar` variable as per your need in your component.

Example with mat-slide-toggle

TS Code:

```
checked = false;
disabled = false;
```

HTML Code:

```
<input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="checked">
<mat-slide-toggle [disabled]="checked">
    Slide me!
</mat-slide-toggle>
```

Now in the above example, if you checked the checkbox checked variable will be updated and if checked equals true then your toggle will be disabled.

Comment: Adding the ngModel glitches out my checkboxes :/ it does not work

Comment: can you please share your code as i can understand more

Comment: correct me if I am wrong, you just want to disabled toggle once the checkbox is checked right?

Comment: Once it's unchecked, yes

Comment: Then you can write checked event of checkbox and in that event, you can update the variable value to true or false as per your requirement.

Comment: For some reason, the ngModel is makingmy input break

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186360/discussion-between-sneha-pawar-and-ch4b).

Comment: If i use the variable-update in the back end, how can i specify whiich mat-slide should be affected? Because they are in a *ngFor

Comment: You can keep a status property into your array this will bind to the particular mat-toggle

Comment: how do i do that?

Comment: Why your ngmodel is not working? Whats the error to use this?

Comment: For some reason, my *ngFor stops working, and no data is brought from my db

Comment: Are you getting any error in console about ngModel or ngFor?

Comment: @CH4B have you checked shared stackBlitz?

Comment: Yes, it does quite what i need, but it does not work on my case

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the requirement correctly:

HTML Code:

```
<div *ngFor="let obj of list">
  <mat-checkbox [(ngModel)]="obj.inTeam">In Team</mat-checkbox>
  <br><br>
  <mat-slide-toggle [(ngModel)]="obj.inTeam">Active</mat-slide-toggle>
</div>
```

TS Code:

```
list = [
    { id : 1,inTeam: false, isActive: false },
    { id : 3,inTeam: false, isActive: false },
    { id : 3,inTeam: false, isActive: false },
    { id : 4,inTeam: false, isActive: false }
]
```

[`StackBlitz`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yzj7w6-hjcpks)

Comment: [(ngModel)] makes my input stop working, i need another way